# Multi-page Airconsole controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine, airconsole

I'm just starting to create a controller for use with Airconsole. I'd like it to be somewhat complicated and will be using Angular to create different pages.

In Unity, I can drag in a `controller.html` file. However, I've been getting resource not found errors when I try to access say `controller.js` or `controller.css`. How can I upload multliple files to the Airconsole host? Is there a general pattern used by other games?

So far I'm considering

1. hosting my app separately and just redirecting to my separate web page. This seems to give errors in the emulator though.
2. Compiling the entire app into just one HTML file.. Not sure how to get these entirely into one file. When I run `ng build` I get a smaller `dist` compiled file, but it still consists of several smaller files. Will try dragging that into Unity and trying again. But dragging the entire Angular project inside Unity felt like a really bad idea..
3. Link to files hosted on separate pages but still have the uploaded HTML file do something.. But not sure how much I need to do here vs how much I can move to other files that I host.

Comment: AirConsole only requires you to have a screen.html for the screen part and a controller.html for the controllers. These files are called when you call the game and distributed to their rightfull devices. Past that, you can do whatever you want. A controller can be a full website if you wish, and I'm always building my controller as that, on my Webstorm IDE using my browser to test. Now if the question is having multiple html files, I think it should  work, the problem is that it would refire a onConnect. You talk about .css and .js files, that works, 200% sure, I'm always segregating my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My basic "how to include other files" question was answered well by another question: [How to include js and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786394/how-to-include-js-and-css-file-from-air-console-with-unity-plugin).

For the more generic question of working with Angular, I still haven't quite figured it out. But what I'm doing at the moment:

I have an Angular project outside of Unity. I run `ng build` to compile everything into a folder `dist`. Then two options work:

Deploy the `dist` folder to static file hosting and change `index.html`'s relative links to point to the separately hosted files with `<base href="https://cloudfilehosting/airconsole-host/">`

OR

Copy the `dist` folder into Unity's `Assets/WebGLTemplates/AirConsole` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your controller using `controller.html` with Angular (1?!), have different pages (e.g. via `ng-include` and the angular routing module) and upload everything to AirConsole (developers).

By using `ng-include` you can have multiple .html views you dynamically load into the controller.html.

I once wrote an example app for AirConsole and Angular:
https://github.com/francois-n-dream/airconsole-angular-phaser

Just think of it as if you would make a (mobile) website which in addition uses the AirConsole API for device communication.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you have an example with Unity as the screen end? Because the Unity plugin just has a "please drag in your controller.html" section which just takes one file. Would love to know more about how the uploading of the web page works!

Comment: The upload is explained here: https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/publish - you just have to use the Unity export instead. Also: if your controller needs additional files like images or fonts, put them in the folder “Assets/WebGLTemplates/AirConsole”. Does that help?! :)