# How to Include .js and .css file from air-console with unity plugin?

Tags: airconsole

We are trying to create an air-console game using the Unity Plugin. However, the .html has both .css and .js included it. How can I separate them?

We have attempted to move the styles to a .css file and link to .html file by adding this line and [This how my unity file directory appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYBFN.png).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="controller.css">
```

Creating a separate .css file produces an error::
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)[This is the error we are getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcH5h.jpg).

How can we Include .css file into unity plugin without running into error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have your css file within the folder WebGLTemplates/AirConsole.